# RavenDb: OnBeforeStore / OnAfterSaveChanges not firing when perfoming Patch or Add Attachment

Tags: ravendb

I want to make sure that every time I make a change to a document, a certain action is performed. For this I wanted to use OnBeforeStore or OnAfterSaveChanges.
Unfortunately, these two events are not triggered when I save a change via patch or add/delete an attachment.

We use the CQRS pattern and have several commands making changes to entities / collections. I need a central place to execute every change to a particular collection, no matter which command is used.

Is there such a thing in RavenDB?

Comment: Which syntax are you using for Patching?  Session-typed-syntax -or- Operations-syntax ?  https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document#examples

Comment: Did you try with ```OnBeforeConversionToDocument``` ?  https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/session/how-to/subscribe-to-events#onbeforeconversiontodocument

Comment: Im using session-typed-syntax.How do i use OnBeforeConversionToDocument? There is no public Event in the DocumentStore?

Comment: Okay... this event does not exist in the interface IDocumentStore; I tried it with the DocumentStore itself, but without any luck. Its also just triggert when i save full entities :-/

Comment: ```OnBeforeConversionToDocument``` was added in 4.2

Comment: @Danielle yep, but not in the interface itself [link](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/79e76b2cab850e2b6ed3752bc60fd07fdb82274e/src/Raven.Client/Documents/IDocumentStore.cs) | dont know if bug/feature | i tried it with the DocumentStoreBase, but without any luck. These events are not fired within the patch-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "central place" that track every change to collection.

About the OnAfterSaveChanges event, it should fire on those actions too.
https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-13906